# How can I replace the last comma in a string with 'and'?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string which is separated by commas

```
'apple,ball,cat'
```

I want to replace the last comma with "and" so that it becomes

```
'apple,ball and cat'
```

Comment: `apple, ball, and cat`  Long live the Oxford comma!

Answer (score 4):

`rpartition` will be your friend here:

```
def replace_last(string, delimiter, replacement):
    start, _, end = string.rpartition(delimiter)
    return start + replacement + end

print(replace_last('apple,ball,cat', ',', ' and '))
```

```
>>> print(replace_last('apple,ball,cat', ',', ' and '))
apple,ball and cat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split a string by char with .split()

```
String = 'apple,ball,cat'
s = String.split(",")
```

Output --> ['apple','ball','cat']

Now you can select all elements without the last

```
s = String.split(",")[:-1]
```

Output --> ['apple','ball']

Now use the join function and connect these elements with ',' between

```
string2 = ",".join(String.split(",")[:-1])
```

Output --> apple,ball

Now add the last element with an "and"

```
string2 = ",".join(String.split(",")[:-1]) + " and " + String.split(",")[-1]
```

Output --> apple,ball and cat

I don't know if it's the best method, but it is one method ;)
Also you can add more elements to your string and this method will still work.

Full Code:

```
String = 'apple,ball,cat'
string2 = ",".join(String.split(",")[:-1]) + " and " + String.split(",")[-1]
```

The answer from @AKX is better ;)

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the string, replace the first comma with the reverse of 'and' and then reverse the result:

```
'apple,ball,cat'[::-1].replace(',', ' dna ', 1)[::-1]

>>> 'apple,ball and cat'
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer from AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63176522/1519716) is great, but if there are no commas, it has to be like this:

```
def replace_last(string, delimiter=',', replacement=', and'):
    start, found_sep, end = string.rpartition(delimiter)
    if found_sep:
        return start + replacement + end
    return start + end
```

Comment: Good catch! Though, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition): _"If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing two empty strings, followed by the string itself,"_ so only `end` really needs to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative by using regex

```
re.sub(r',', '.', String[::-1], 1)[::-1]
```

- Reverses the string
- replaces 1 ',' with '.'
- Reverses the result

Compared the performance with AKX's solution, this version is terrible.

```
In [39]: def f1(s):
    ...:     start, _, end = s.rpartition(',')
    ...:     return start + '.' + end

In [40]: def f2(s):
    ...:     return re.sub(r',', '.', s[::-1], 1)[::-1]
    ...:

In [44]: %timeit f1(s)
364 ns ± 8.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [45]: %timeit f2(s)
1.51 µs ± 5.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```